How to add a reciting pitch and invisible notes in Gregorio in a space-efficient way?
How write a hollow note / punctum cavum / void note as the reciting pitch and then a series of invisible notes in Gregorio in a space efficiant fasion?
In engraving a leaflet using Gregorio, I am following some of the style conventions of the The RSCM Guide to Plainchant's second part, "An Anthology of Plainchant," specifically the use of void notes to represent the recitation pitch.
Adding the reciting pitch on the first word, a bunch of text, and then the cadence did not work (e.g., word(hx) word word cadence(fh::)). So I added an empty note with (), as recommended by this post, after every word. This fixed some issues, but not all. The main problem is that it still takes up much more space than writing actual notes.
I was able to remedy some of the spacing issues by adding the larger neumatic space // after the reciting note (e.g., (hx//), but the score below goes onto the next line by one word using the void-note style reciting pitch, whereas repeating the note with every syllable keeps it on one line. How can I fix this so that the style I want takes us a more reasonable amount of space?
Some helpful images and code:
Gabc file code (the -- between the e and vil is to add a hyphen since it doesn't hyphenate the extra space there automatically):
name: Lords_Prayer_Conc;
%%
(f3)
And(hr//) lead() us() not() into() tempta--()tion;(f,) but(hr//) deliver() us() from() e--()vil.(f::h+)

TeX file code (much of the stuff here is to remove the margins completely since I'm importing it into InDesign):
% !TEX program = LuaLaTeX+se
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{"Sabon LT Pro Roman"}[
BoldFont = "Sabon LT Pro Bold",
ItalicFont = "Sabon LT Pro Italic",
BoldItalicFont = "Sabon LT Pro BoldItalic"]
\usepackage[fontsize=13]{scrextend}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\hoffset-1in
\voffset-1in
\newbox\scorebox
\setbox\scorebox=\vbox{\hsize=30pc\relax % change the width of the score here

\gresetinitiallines{0}
\gregorioscore{Lords_Prayer_Conc}
}

\pagewidth\wd\scorebox
\pageheight\dimexpr\ht\scorebox+\dp\scorebox\relax

\shipout\box\scorebox


\end{document}

The result with the void-note style reciting tone:

The result, repeating the reciting tone with every syllable, which has my preferred spacing:

The style I want to emulate looks like:


Welcome to tex.sx.

I've partially fixed the problem – more of a Band-Aid. Whereas the empty notes () were necessary for other chants, removing almost all of them brought it down to one line. The new code is And(hr) lead us not into tempta--()tion;(f,) but(hr) deliver us from e--()vil.(f::h+).
However, I want a solution that will work in every, or nearly every, instance, so, while the problem is solved for now, it is not the ultimate solution.

I have been editing various chants to put them into this form for a little bit now, and it seems that a different solution is needed in most instances, whether it be the presence/absence of empty notes () or the larger neumatic space (which only sometimes needs to be there). A comprehensive solution would be greatly appreciated.

I am not a user of LuaLaTeX and cannot compile your code, neither can I find a manual, but as user of MusiXTeX with some use of reciting tones, I put the text in those cases in between {}, making a box of it. The space inside is not extended. Actually, in the printed example, There is a hyphen between Glo and ry, which I do not understand, because the whole word is on the same reciting tone, while there is no hyphen in Amen, which has two notes. Printed music often makes concessions to logics due to (lack of) space.

Thank you, @C.Peters! I'm not familiar with MusiXTeX, so I'm not sure how it works with that, but it seems your solution has fixed part of the problem (like the example in my initial question). Using {} around the final syllable to center the neum on the that syllable has fixed the hypanization and spacing issues in chants that do not go over one line!!! However, chants that go over one line still take far more space with the reciting note than with a repeated note.

@Vtex Would something like \raggedright help? I believe that articles fill lines.

@C.Peters \raggedright didn't work. Gregorio seems to do spacing itself, so I think it would need to be in the Gabc file or a Gregorio macro in the TeX file.

I tried to work with this package, resulting in the following:
Your gabc-file results in the first picture, thus on one single line, run once with LuaLaTeX.

My second gabc-file results in the second picture:
name: Lords_Prayer_Conc;
%%
(f3)
And(hr) {lead us not into tempta}-tion;(f,) but(hr//) {deliver us from e}-()vil.(f::h+)


My third gabc-file results in the third picture:
name: Lords_Prayer_Conc;
%%
(f3)
And(hr) {lead us not into tempta}()-~tion;(f,) but(hr) {deliver us from e}()-~vil.(f::h+)


So, you can do a lot of things to influence the spacing, but, from your own files it is not evident, why your result is presented on two lines. I could not get rid of the space at the place of (), therefore I consider nr. 3 the most balanced. It should be possible to remove the spacing at (), but \rlap does not work, and I haven't yet tried \lsong or other MusiXTeX code.
If you provide for some longer text where you are sure that extends any lines, I could try to minimize the spacing there, but remind: most music editors like filled lines and therefore stretch text in an ugly way.
Edit: After having studied GregorioRef.pdf, page 42, I added some forced centers, and my gabc-file looks like this:
name: Lords_Prayer_Conc;
%%
(f3)
{{And} lead us not into tempta}(hr)tion;(f,) {{but} deliver us from e}(hr)vil.(f::h+)

meaning that I deleted empty notes, which automatically take a minimum of space.
Add \gresethyphen{force} to your .tex-file (after \gresetinitiallines{0}), switch it on and off to see the difference.

Thank you! I think the reason you couldn't replicate the going-over-the-line problem because I left out the code that changed the font. I'm using "Sabon LT Pro Roman" at 13pt size (to match the rest of the leaflet) – I've added that code back to the initial question. I think your final solution is the one that works for single line files (although you don't need the extra curly brackets around the whole thing, as far as I understand, just the syllable you want to center the note on). Also, on the subject of multi-line issues, I think you're right about music software always stretching text.

@ Vtex See 6.4.12 Line Breaks of the manual for ragged lines. You will have to decide manually where to break them.
